# Qt, VC 2010 and static libraries

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, static-linking

I need to use a static library in my Qt5 project. I'm using VC++ 2010 as my compiler and QtCreator as IDE.

If I use the dynamic version (.DLL) everything works fine.
If I try to use the static version (.LIB) it seems like the library is looking for other dependencies that can't be satisfied.
Sadly, using the DLL is not an option for my project.

The point is that if I try to use the static library from VC++ IDE everything works fine.
Please note that I can use other VC++ headers without any problem in my Qt project.

It seems like the compiler can find everything it needs (basically, my source code and all the required headers) while the linker is missing something.

> error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_SystemTimeToVariantTime@8 referenced in function "bool __cdecl SystemTimeToMinute(struct _SYSTEMTIME *,unsigned long *)" (?SystemTimeToMinute@@YA_NPAU_SYSTEMTIME@@PAK@Z)

SystemTimeToVariantTime is defined in OleAut32.lib.

Am I wrong expecting the linker to automatically look for needed libraries and headers based on the content of the global variables INCLUDE and LIB?

Comment: Did you try to add "OleAut32.lib" into the list of libraries in your project's configuration: "Properties -> Linker -> Input : Additional Dependencies"

Comment: Yes even if in QtCreator it's slightly different.
Anyhow, it doesn't work. Same error message

Comment: Do you have 'Windows SDK' installed in your system?

Comment: Yes I do. As I said I'm able to use any SDK or VC++ header in my project, included those used when I link to the dynamic version of this library.

Comment: Thank you for your help Vahancho, I solved the problem. It was a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem was that I was trying to include external (SDK) libraries using

LIBS += -l OleAut32.lib

While I had to simply use

LIBS += OleAut32.lib

Well, problem solved.
I hope this can help someone in the future!